# cv.imshow() is not working - cv2 method - pycharm

Tags: python, opencv

im new to python and coding. i wanted to play around with cv2 and learn the module but came across a problem my first go. Im sure its a simple fix however the tutorial video im watching has the same code.

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread("dog.png")
cv.imshow("Output", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

#angrey red error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jaski/PycharmProjects/opencvpython1/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    cv.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: I get this error when there is no dog.png. Maybe check that that file is actually in the current directory?

Comment: i dragged over the file into pycharm and i can open the file.

Comment: try absolute path. Probably you are not in the right working directory. Try to write a "dog.txt" file and check in which directory it was written.

Comment: everything is working fine now. thanks for the help